# Postgres query using index does never finish

Tags: postgresql-performance

So I have the following 3 tables:

```
create table imdb_dev.dim_title
(
    id                 uuid        not null,
    tconst             varchar(10) not null,
    title_type_id      uuid        not null,
    primary_title      text,
    original_title     text,
    is_adult           boolean,
    start_year         integer,
    end_year           integer,
    runtime_in_minutes integer,
    constraint dim_title_pkey
        primary key (id),
    constraint dim_title_title_type_id_fkey
        foreign key (title_type_id) references imdb_dev.dim_title_type
);

create table imdb_dev.dim_title_type
(
    id         uuid not null,
    title_type text not null,
    constraint dim_title_type_pkey
        primary key (id)
);

create table staging.title_basics
(
    tconst         varchar(10) not null,
    titletype      varchar(20) not null,
    primarytitle   text,
    originaltitle  text,
    isadult        boolean,
    startyear      integer,
    endyear        integer,
    runtimeminutes integer,
    genres         text,
    constraint title_basics_pkey
        primary key (tconst, titletype)
)
    partition by LIST (titletype);
```

I want to select rows that exist in `title_basics` and insert then in `dim_title`. Both `dim_title` and `title_basics` have around 8 million rows while `dim_title_type` is just a mapping table with just 12 rows.

This is the query I'm using to select the rows I need to insert. For some reason it just keeps running and never finishes:

```
SELECT
    md5(tconst)::UUID AS id,
    tconst,
    tt.id AS title_type_id,
    tb.primarytitle AS primary_title,
    tb.originaltitle AS original_title,
    tb.isadult AS is_adult,
    tb.startyear AS start_year,
    tb.endyear AS end_year,
    tb.runtimeminutes AS runtime_in_minutes
FROM
    "funbro"."staging"."title_basics" tb
LEFT JOIN
    "funbro"."imdb_dev"."dim_title_type" tt ON tt.title_type = tb.titleType

WHERE md5(tconst)::UUID NOT IN (select id from "funbro"."imdb_dev"."dim_title")
;
```

I'm surely doing something wrong but I fail to see what that is. This is the query plan:

```
Gather  (cost=1001.27..533568642515.39 rows=4040707 width=97)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1.27..533568237444.69 rows=1683628 width=97)
        Hash Cond: ((tb.titletype)::text = tt.title_type)
        ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..533568197457.27 rows=1683627 width=73)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics_tvepisode tb_4  (cost=0.00..381512705366.11 rows=1231620 width=75)
                    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
                    SubPlan 1
                      ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..289561.20 rows=8081413 width=16)
                            ->  Seq Scan on dim_title  (cost=0.00..209693.13 rows=8081413 width=16)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics_short tb_3  (cost=0.00..52946232635.92 rows=170924 width=63)
                    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics_movie tb_1  (cost=0.00..37574087716.28 rows=121299 width=65)
                    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics_video tb_7  (cost=0.00..20256814175.33 rows=65394 width=81)
                    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics_tvseries tb_6  (cost=0.00..19194394831.39 rows=61965 width=68)
                    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics_tvmovie tb_5  (cost=0.00..12033907879.19 rows=38848 width=77)
                    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics_others tb_2  (cost=0.00..10050046434.90 rows=32444 width=79)
                    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.12..1.12 rows=12 width=25)
              ->  Seq Scan on dim_title_type tt  (cost=0.00..1.12 rows=12 width=25)
```

These are the specs of the machine where Postgres 13 is running. The disk is an SSD. The Postgres configuration is the default one:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but: `md5(cast(concat(coalesce(cast(tconst as varchar), '')) as varchar))` can be simplified to `md5(coalesce(tconst, ''))`

Comment: The expression on the `tcast` column won't use any index, so you'll always get a Seq Scan on `title_basics`. You could try to create an index on `title_basics ( md5(coalesce(tconst, ''))::uuid)`  (after simplifying the expression in the WHERE clause). But I find this comparison (md5 of a text column converted to a UUID compared with a UUID column) highly irritating

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The reason for that cast is that `title_basics` is a staging table where data lands from an external storage so unfortunately, the uuid that exists in `dim_titles` is not directly available. I'll try to create the index of that expression!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so I created the index like this:

create index title_basics_id_uuid on staging.title_basics
(( md5(tconst)::UUID ));

But when running the query using md5(tconst)::UUID in the where clause predicate I still getting a seq scan in the query plan... Any idea?

        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics tb  (cost=0.00..522111602764.27 rows=1685510 width=72)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out the problem.

Firstly, I thought that adding an index as an expression at `staging.title_basics` as suggested would make the query planner use the index, but I did that and still faced the same problem: Postgres would keep doing a Seq Scan:

```
create index title_basics_id_uuid on staging.title_basics
(( md5(tconst)::UUID ));
```

The real problem is that using `NOT IN` in the `where` predicate is super inefficient. Changing that for a LEFT JOIN where id is null makes the query finish in less than 1 minute. Reference: wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN

Final query:

```
SELECT
    md5(tb.tconst)::UUID as id,
    tt.id AS title_type_id,
    tb.primarytitle AS primary_title,
    tb.originaltitle AS original_title,
    tb.isadult AS is_adult,
    tb.startyear AS start_year,
    tb.endyear AS end_year,
    tb.runtimeminutes AS runtime_in_minutes
FROM
    "funbro"."staging"."title_basics" tb
LEFT JOIN
    "funbro"."imdb_dev"."dim_title_type" tt ON tt.title_type = tb.titleType
LEFT JOIN
    imdb_dev.dim_title t ON md5(tb.tconst)::UUID = t.id

WHERE t.id is null
;
```